# Facing FileNotFoundException while accessing JSON File in classpath using java in docker containers(SprintBootApplication)

Tags: java, json, linux, docker, spring-boot

I'm Facing a FileNotFoundException while loading a JSON file which is in class path of Java jar using docker containers, it is a Spring-Boot application. This JSON file is available in resource folder . I'm Able to see the JSON file in docker under ./target/classes/ path.

```
Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:folderNm/file.json");
HashMap<String, String> headerMapping = (HashMap<String, String>) parser.parse(new FileReader(resource.getFile().getAbsolutePath()));
```

But I get this exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [folderNm/file.json] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/app.jar!/folderNm/file.json
```

I tried

-> `resource.getFile().getPath();`
-> `resource.getFile().getCanonicalPath();`
-> "`./target/classes/folderName/fileName`" (hardcoded FilePath location)
-> "`/app.jar!/folderNm/file.json`" (hardcoded FilePath location)

```
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("xyz.json");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder responseStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String inputStr;
            while ((inputStr = br.readLine()) != null)
                responseStrBuilder.append(inputStr);
```

none of the way above are running. Kindly Suggest a way to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you tried with Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:/folderNm/file.json"); with leading forward slash?

Comment: I've faced similar problem. And actually it turned out for me that it would be better to simply add the file while building docker image, and then access it simply with path.

I'm not sure if you can do it the other way around. You need to remember that spring boot underneath uses tomcat/jetty/undertow embedded.

Comment: @AntonBelev, I tried with leading / as well, but that did not worked.

Comment: @gmaslowski, Can you please show few lines as to how you could read the file from docker image?

Comment: Following code has worked for me. First I have added JSON file using maven in class path. Second in java i used below code                                   String parsedJSONString = "";
ClassPathResource cpr = new ClassPathResource(filePath); 
byte[] bdata = null;
try {bdata = FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(cpr.getInputStream());
} catch (Exception e1) {
e1.printStackTrace();
}
parsedJSONString = new String(bdata, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that in the maven structure (you are using maven, right?) your file is located at `src/main/resources/folderName/file.json`, the path you pass to `getResourceAsStream` should be **/folderName/file.json**

Actually everything is explained in [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-):

> Before delegation, an absolute resource name is constructed from the
>   given resource name using this algorithm:
>
> - If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of
>     the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.
> - Otherwise,
>     the absolute name is of the following form: modified_package_name/name
>
> Where the modified_package_name is the package name of this object
>   with '/' substituted for '.' ('\u002e').

Basically if you skip the '/' in front, it looks for the *folderName* inside the package of your class. Following code works fine for me:

```
    InputStream inputStream = StackTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/folderName/file.json");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
    StringBuilder responseStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String inputStr;
    while ((inputStr = br.readLine()) != null)
        responseStrBuilder.append(inputStr);
    System.out.println(responseStrBuilder.toString());
```

assuming I have my *file.json* in src/main/resources/folderName. I don't think it has anything to do with docker.
Btw, I think you could make use of [Apache Commons IOUtils.toString](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString(java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) that helps turning InputStream into a String.

Comment: my problem was that front "/" spend so much time on that, thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Create file:

```
src/main/resources/firebase/your_account_json.json
```

Load InputStream:

```
String path = "/firebase/your_account_json.json";
InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder().setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(in))
      .setDatabaseUrl("https://your-project.firebaseio.com")
      .setStorageBucket("your-project.appspot.com")
      .build();
```